# Bluetooth RFCOMM socket with Golang

Tags: sockets, go, bluetooth

I'm trying to open an RFCOMM socket from Go. I have a test setup where the client connects to an echo server. The part that I'm stuck on is setting up the Bluetooth address. In C you have str2ba, which converts the MAC string to a byte array of six elements. In Go it appears it expects the device to be a uint16. I'm not sure how this would work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "syscall"

    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)


func main() {
    fd, err := unix.Socket(syscall.AF_BLUETOOTH, syscall.SOCK_STREAM, unix.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%v\n", err)
    }
    addr := unix.SockaddrHCI{Dev: 1, Channel: 1}
    unix.Connect(fd, addr)
    unix.Write(fd, []byte("Hello"))
    var data []byte
    unix.Read(fd, data)
    fmt.Printf("Received: %v\n", string(data))
}
```

The `Dev` member in `unix.SockaddrHCI` is a uint16 and I think this is to represent the Bluetooth MAC. Is this correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think that topicstarter already doesn't need this answer, but I needed it yesterday )) Kinda found right answer, so let me share the code that worked in my case (it was a HC06 bluetooth module for Arduino). I assume that module already was bt discovered and paired (e.g by means of bluetoothctl).

```golang
package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "syscall"

    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

func main() {
    mac := str2ba("00:19:10:08:FE:08") // YOUR BLUETOOTH MAC ADDRESS HERE

    fd, err := unix.Socket(syscall.AF_BLUETOOTH, syscall.SOCK_STREAM, unix.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
    check(err)
    addr := &unix.SockaddrRFCOMM{Addr: mac, Channel: 1}

    var data = make([]byte, 50)
    logrus.Print("connecting...")
    err = unix.Connect(fd, addr)
    check(err)
    defer unix.Close(fd)
    logrus.Println("done")

    for {
        n, err := unix.Read(fd, data)
        check(err)
        if n > 0 {
            logrus.Infof("Received: %v\n", string(data[:n]))
        }
    }
}

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Fatal(err)
    }
}

// str2ba converts MAC address string representation to little-endian byte array
func str2ba(addr string) [6]byte {
    a := strings.Split(addr, ":")
    var b [6]byte
    for i, tmp := range a {
        u, _ := strconv.ParseUint(tmp, 16, 8)
        b[len(b)-1-i] = byte(u)
    }
    return b
}
```